# Postgres Join Query is SOMETIMES taking the cartesian product

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I'm attempting to join multiple tables for one query and I am getting inconsistent results from the database, I believe my query is taking the cartesian product of all the users, when I only want users who are in the DirectConversation.

The Schema for reference:

[image: This is the schema for the tables in question, is it possible this is an error with my schema?]

The query is (where $id stands for the variable User.id):

```SQL
SELECT c.*, count(dm.id), 
u1.first_name, u1.last_name, u1.company, u1.picture, 
u2.first_name, u2.last_name, u2.company, u2.picture
FROM "DirectConversation" as c, "DirectMessage" as dm, "Profile" as u1, "Profile" as u2
WHERE u1."id_User" = c."id_User1"
AND u2."id_User" = c."id_User2"
AND c.id = dm."id_DirectConversation" 
AND dm.viewed = 'f' AND dm.deleted = 'f'
AND c."id_User1" = $id OR c."id_User2" = $id
GROUP BY c.id, u1.id, u2.id;
```

The expected result (the result when the user id = 1 ):

```
id | id_User1 | id_User2 | count | first_name | last_name |      company       |                                   picture                                   | first_name | last_name |    company     |                                 picture                                  
----+----------+----------+-------+------------+-----------+--------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------+-----------+----------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  1 |        1 |        2 |     3 | Albert     | Einstein  | alberts inventions | http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d3/Albert_Einstein_Head.jpg | Nikola     | Tesla     | Teslas Widgets | http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/79/Tesla_circa_1890.jpeg
(1 row)

(END)
```

The error result (the result when the user id= 2):

```
id | id_User1 | id_User2 | count | first_name | last_name |      company       |                                                    picture                                                     | first_name | last_name |      company       |                                                    picture                                                     
----+----------+----------+-------+------------+-----------+--------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------+-----------+--------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  1 |        1 |        2 |     4 | Albert     | Einstein  | alberts inventions | http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d3/Albert_Einstein_Head.jpg                                    | Albert     | Einstein  | alberts inventions | http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d3/Albert_Einstein_Head.jpg
  1 |        1 |        2 |     4 | Albert     | Einstein  | alberts inventions | http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d3/Albert_Einstein_Head.jpg                                    | Nikola     | Tesla     | Teslas Widgets     | http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/79/Tesla_circa_1890.jpeg
  1 |        1 |        2 |     4 | Albert     | Einstein  | alberts inventions | http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d3/Albert_Einstein_Head.jpg                                    | Rosalind   | Franklin  | DNA R US           | http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/9/97/Rosalind_Franklin.jpg
  1 |        1 |        2 |     4 | Albert     | Einstein  | alberts inventions | http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d3/Albert_Einstein_Head.jpg                                    | Charles    | Babbage   | Babbages Cabbages  | http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/6b/Charles_Babbage_-_1860.jpg
```

... Note this was truncated for brevity. I believe this is taking the cartesian product of all the users, however I am unaware as to why

The version of postgres I'm using:

### version

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 PostgreSQL 9.3.6 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 4.8.2, 64-bit
```

Comment: because you didn't properly create your join statement

Comment: use the JOIN statement to join your tables instead of just commas and use the ON statement to say which values need to be the same, not the where clause

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just moved your where clauses for the joins to the ON statement and made proper joins, if this doesn't work I'll set up a sqlfiddle and see what the problem with this sql is

```
SELECT c.*, count(dm.id), 
    u1.first_name, u1.last_name, u1.company, u1.picture, 
    u2.first_name, u2.last_name, u2.company, u2.picture
    FROM "DirectConversation" c
    JOIN "DirectMessage" dm ON c.id = dm."id_DirectConversation" 
    JOIN "Profile" u1 ON u1."id_User" = c."id_User1"
    JOIN "Profile" u2 ON u2."id_User" = c."id_User2"
    WHERE 
    dm.viewed = 'f' AND dm.deleted = 'f'
    AND (c."id_User1" = $id OR c."id_User2" = $id)
    GROUP BY c.id, u1.id, u2.id;
```

Edit: grouped the OR clause just to be safe

Comment: Looks great, thanks Jeremy. I thought I could get away with the simpler notation but you're right, using proper joins here was the way to go.

Comment: did it fix your problem?

Comment: Yes, there is no longer a cartesian product of all the users when using id = 2. Thus I believe you were correct in your assessment that the join statement wasn't properly formed.

Comment: Alright, glad I could help, try to make it a habit to write out your joins, you never know what you're going to get if you don't :D

Comment: @Blakedallen: combining `AND` and `OR` conditions without using parentheses is usually a bug waiting to happen. I think you actually want:  `AND (c."id_User1" = $id OR c."id_User2" = $id)`

Comment: @JeremyC I hit one more snag, I'd like to return the count of only direct messages which haven't been viewed (dm.viewed = 'f') which could be zero... this query will return 0 rows when all messages have been read, any thoughts on how to return a count of zero and still return the other data?

Comment: Nevermind, I was able to sum on the number of viewed = 'f' by using a case statement. ```SELECT c.*, SUM(case when dm.viewed = 'f' then 1 else 0 end), ...``` *note this removes the later check ```WHERE dm.viewed = 'f'```